# Assign properties of one IEnumerable to another

Tags: c#

I have a class Person:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

and a class Email:

```
public class Email
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and I have IEnumerables of both:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Persons;

public IEnumerable<Email> Emails;
```

I want to to a process to assign all emails to the persons, based on equal Id.

I was trying something like

```
foreach (var person in Persons.Where(p => p.Id.Equals(Emails.Select(x=>x.Id))))
    {
        person.Email = Emails.Select(e => e.EmailAddress);
    }
```

but this is where I'm struggling a bit, the working versions I saw are using 2 foreach, which I understand is not performing. what could be the approach to assign 1 email to each person where `Persons.Id == Emails.Id` ?

Comment: How are persons and emails linked? I doubt that the logic is correct that a Person.Id should match with an Email.Id. If it's the Email that should match with the EmailAddress, then it's not clear what you want to assign.

Comment: via the ID (this is an example, I was to assign the EmailAddress from Emails to the Email in Persons where the ID from Persons ==  the ID from Emails

Comment: Are you sure that the EmailIId is not the Id of the Email but the Id of the Person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var person in Persons)
  {
     var email = Emails.FirstOrDefault(email => email.Id == person.Id);
     if(email != null)
       person.Email = email.Email;
  }
```

Comment: Hello, this looks good, however, how should I go the other way around? a foreach on the emails, but assign the emailAddress to the email in Persons?  (the emails is shorter so faster to loop)